# Hammer js dragging

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I have the following code which I got from the hammer documentation, however the listener isn't firing for me. I can't figure out why I can't get drag to work.

Also, I attempted to do my own drag like feature using tap, pan, but again how do I get an event for detecting a release? I see examples online with people using: `touch.on("release", function(ev) {});` but I get absolutely nothing.

```
var options = {
      dragLockToAxis: true,
      dragBlockHorizontal: true
    };
            //Hammer.js dependency. Setup touch
            touch = new Hammer(el, options);



            touch.on("dragleft dragright", function(ev) {
                console.log("handle released");
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `pan` not `drag` (not sure when they changed it)

http://jsbin.com/suleyilejili/2/edit

http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pan/